# Proxy setting to block file upload in telegram web

Tags: websocket, proxy, telegram, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I want to block file upload (sending image, file, attachment) in telegram web.
I found this link [https://community.broadcom.com/symantecenterprise/discussion/how-to-block-file-upload-via-whatsapp-web](https://stackoverflow.com) to block file upload in whatsapp web. But find nothing for telegram web.

Maybe anyone in here know how to do that using proxy or any other method is okay

I have tried to block whatsapp web from the tutorial above and works. I hope I can find a way for telegram web